# Error message dynamically creating "ul" and "li" and dispositioning the "radio button"

Tags: javascript, html, css, parsley.js

I've got the below code when I inspected. I see that the `ul` and `li` are created dynamically on validation, which is expected.

However, the error message dispositions the next radio button in the group to the next line and put the message on the first line after the first radio button. Any idea to force the message to next line or probably after 2nd radio button without it dispositioning the buttons.

I use data-parsley-required="required". I am planning to put a div after the label  but don't know how to target the error message there as only thing that I use in label is data-parsley-required="required" removing which it doesn't display the error.

```
<div class="col-pa" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="button err" aria-describedby="parsley-id-multiple-Units">
        <input data-parsley-required="required" id="Gender" name="Units" type="radio" value="Fixed" data-parsley-multiple="Units" data-parsley-id="12"> 
        Fixed
    </label><ul class="validation-errors filled" id="parsley-id-multiple-Units"><li class="parsley-required">This is mandatory</li></ul>
    <label class="button">
        <input data-parsley-required="required" id="Units" name="Units" type="radio" value="Variable" data-parsley-multiple="Units"> 
        Variable
    </label>
</div>
```

**My cshtml Code**

```
<div class="buttons" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="@fixedClass">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Units, "Fixed", new { data_parsley_required = "required" }) 
                    @Translator.GetTextOrDefault("CMS.Value.Units", "Fixed")
                </label>
                <label class="@variableClass">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Units, "Variable", new { data_parsley_required = "required" }) 
                    @Translator.GetTextOrDefault("CMS.Value.Units", "Variable")
                </label>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [parsley.js doc](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/annotated-source/defaults.html), you can configure the options when first initiating `.parsley(options)`. In this case, the option that you're looking for is `errorsWrapper`.

Following is the sample how you can target the error message container.

```js
$(() => {
  var instance = $("#myform").parsley({
    errorsWrapper: ".errorsWrapper"
  });
});
```

```css
.errorsWrapper {
  display: none;
  padding: 4px;
}

.errorsWrapper.filled {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.8.1/parsley.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
    <label class="button err" aria-describedby="parsley-id-multiple-Units">
        <input name="Units" type="radio" value="Fixed" data-parsley-multiple="Units" data-parsley-required="required" /> 
        Fixed
    </label>
    <label class="button">
        <input name="Units" type="radio" value="Variable" data-parsley-multiple="Units" data-parsley-required="required" /> 
        Variable
    </label>

    <ul class="errorsWrapper">
    </ul>
    
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default validate" />
</form>
```

They also have some useful [demos](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples.html) that is quite useful to understand how the plugin works.

Comment: Thank you, My code doesn't have the UL and LI. Its dynamically creating. I updated my question with My Code in cshtml. Please help on how to apply

Comment: I managed to finally show error message down, with the help of similar approach, but now two times erro message shwon. Can you please help? I used a div with ID and targetted the error message to that ID like this data_parsley_errors_container = "#errorContainer"  <div id="errorContainer" class="error-container col-xs-12"></div>

Comment: @Learner Parsley probably recognize more than one different fields being not valid. If you want to link elements validation like checkbox with different names, you need to specify `data-parsley-multiple`. And also, there's another attribute that may support this which is `data-parsley-group`. In your updated question, your cshtml fails to specify `data-parsley-multiple` in your input fields.

Comment: No, it doesn't help me. I managed to put data-parsley-errors-container in upper div so now it shows error message at right place. But it also displays error message at right side. Twice

Comment: As you recommended, when I put multiple, all other controls gets screwed up

Comment: I don't understand, why would other controls get screwed up. Can you elaborate more?